# read console log on amazon web services for nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Hi I have a node app deployed via AWS beanstalk.

Is there a way to read the console logs in my node script anywhere on AWS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way to read your logs outside of sshing into your instance is to use a third-party service like [Logentries](https://logentries.com/) or [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the console output, then see the [getConsoleOutput SDK reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#getConsoleOutput-property). For example:

```
var params = {
  InstanceId: 'STRING_VALUE', // required
  DryRun: true || false,
};
ec2.getConsoleOutput(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: I actually can't even deploy the app when I have var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  I keep getting 502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.4.7

Comment: @user1424508 Problem locating the AWS node.js SDK? Have you tried raising a support case with AWS? I note that you also posted this under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797755/setting-up-aws-sdk-for-node-js-keeps-returning-502.